# Using the end address of the program as a value of a variable

Tags: arm, iar

I want to use in my source code the end address (as a value of a variable) of my program that will be stored in the ROM after download. I did found the way to use in the source code symbols defined in the linker script file, but i did not find any symbols that are related to the end address of the program.

Do you have any idea how can i get this Information?

Thanks for the help. Regards.

Comment: In gcc you define this at the end of your linker script. It might be similar for iar. Check the manual carefully I say.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. In the linker script just the end address of the Rom Region is defined, but that one is different from the actual end address of the program that will be stored in the Rom.

Comment: Sounds like you need to work on the linker script some more.  I dont know about iar, but subtle changes in placement in a gnu ld linker script makes a huge difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the intrinsic function `__segment_end`. For example (assuming code is stored in the segment `CODE`):

```
#pragma segment="CODE"

void * my_f(void) { return __segment_end("CODE"); }
```